# Online learning that "forgets" older aspects learned? (short-term memory)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multi-class, online-algorithms, filter

I am looking for an online learning classifier that is highly adaptable and has only short-term memory. I need such a think in a object tracking system with high-dimensional feature vectors.

Maybe a system with a constant learning rate could be useful?

Any pointers to literature? Any useful advice?

Answer (score 1):

You Should look up *stochastic gradient descent*. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/ and wikipedia.

I also think Kalman Filter will do what you ask for. Just set a high learning rate.

However to high learning rate removes the "learning" from the system. If past experience have no effect (or negible) on the decision then no learning.

Comment: I am not sure the Kalman Filter would work in this situation: I am going to have high-dimensional feature vectors (colors, edge orientations...), while I saw the Kalman filter working just on coordinates and a few hidden variables. Moreover the Kalman filter, in the end is going to be just a single learned multivariate normal distribution, while maybe I need something more complex. But I will have a look on stochastic gradient descent, this might be helpful.

Comment: By the way, how would you use the stochastic gradient descent? How would you use if for a scoring/classification system such the one I need?

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about the underlying model?

Comment: It's a football player tracker, and the classifier should learn from the rectangle containing a specific player, over several frames

Comment: As far as i know SGD assumes a linear classifier. Seems like you maybe do something more complex. What kinda classifier do you use or think you want to use?

Comment: Surely, it has to be more complex. I was thinking about a One-Class-SVM classifier. Discovered that recently: allows to just provide positive examples (and it's not linear via the kernel).

Comment: Actually, anything from Random Forest to Neural Networks might be useful, if it has online learning capability and "concept drift" short-term memory.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if this is good practice, but what about having two models. One fitted on all historical data and one fitted on recent data, then  you can use an weighted average of those two models.

The weight then determines how much importance you put on recent data and how much you put on historical.

Comment: why would I need a model with historical data? I mean, your idea could work, but a few disadvantage being the introduction of an additional parameter (+ another one that establishes the size of the "recent" window). Moreover, with SVMs it gets tricky to combine multiple models, because the "scores" are distances from the separation boundary, which might be non-trivial to combine. But maybe you have some suggestion on how to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a kernel-based algorithm that allows you to explicitly deal with forgetting. It's called kernel recursive least-squares tracker ([journal paper link](https://gtas.unican.es/pub/282)) Data can be anything as long as you can formulate a [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method) on them.

The algorithm is formulated for regression though, but one of the cited papers formulates the same framework for classification (though only for stationary scenarios): L. Csató and M. Opper. Sparse online Gaussian processes. Neural Computation, 14(2):641-669, 2002.